# ArcMap layout dynamic text, remove group by decimal point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, data-driven-pages, dynamic-text

I'm currently designing layout of my data driven pages map.
I would like to put x/y coordinates in corner of current layout view.
I'm using text box with dynamic text code like this:

```
<dyn type="dataFrame" name="DataFrameName" property="lowerRight.x" decimalPlaces="0"/>
```

Result of this code is: 5.578.750

I would like to know is there a way to remove group by decimal point formatting? Some kind of additional parameter inside code?
My second goal is to wrap number after point so coordinates look like this:

```
5
578
750
```

I'm working in ArcMap 10.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Windows you can change the decimal point settings in the Control Panel and these will be applied in ArcMap.
eg Windows 7 Control Panel:
Click Clock,Language, and Region; Click Change he date, time, or number format; Click Additional Settings; Digit grouping symbol - replace "." with " ".

To wrap the numbers use the Drawing toolbar and draw the Rectangle Text. Paste the code into the rectangle. You can shape the rectangle so that it wraps the text how you like.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Changing number format in Contorl panel works but this changes entire windows settings. I can conclude thar ArcMap doesn't have iternal option to remove digit grouping in my case. I've tried to draw a rectangle text box but text is wrapped word only, not letter. So when I shrink text box to be too small, entire coordinate is gone and the box is empty.

Comment: The wrapping works once you have removed the decimal separators and replaced them with spaces.